# ASP MVC SignalR between different web applications (Cross domain)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, cross-domain

For my web applications I want realtime updates and this works when I use it within the same web project but not across others.

I have 2 applications : A portal website with announcements and a application where I can add announcements. What I want to do is when someone adds an announcement in the announcement application that the portal should update.

But I can't get this working.

**Startup.cs (Both for Portal and Announcements Project)**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration{};
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
}
```

**Hub (In a shared Class library)**

```
[HubName("announcementsHub")]
public class AnnouncementsHub : Hub
{
    public void UpdateAnnouncements()
    {
        Clients.All.updateAnnouncements();
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml (Portal Application)**

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {

        var announcementsHubProxy = $.connection.announcementsHub;

        announcementsHubProxy.client.updateAnnouncements = function () {
            alert("UPDATE PORTAL");
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();
    })
</script>
```

**Index.cshtml (Announcements Application)**

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {

            var announcementsHubProxy = $.connection.announcementsHub;

            $("#add-announcement").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // submit form

                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    announcementsHubProxy.server.updateAnnouncements();
                });
            });      
    })
</script>
```

I don't get any errors. What am I doing wrong? I assume both applications are connecting to a different connection?

Any help is appreciated! Thx.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the error is. "Doesn't work" is not detailed enough I suppose.

Comment: Your problem is discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449713/how-to-use-signalr-with-cross-domain

Comment: Sorry, but I got no error.. When I copy the code from my portal index.cshtml into the index.cshtml from Announcements it works.

Comment: @NaveedYousaf It seems to be working when I add $.connection.hub.url ='http://localhost:xxx/signalr' But in reality I have multiple applications which all can act as server/client. Any idea how to do this?